# Is there a way to split an operation (division) in python?

Tags: python-3.x, split, division

I was trying to do this code :

```
x = 18.00 /34

a = str(x).split(" /")
print(a)
```

I understood that it would do the operation (18/34) but i was trying to get this:

```
a = ['18.00','34']
```

Is there a way to get this outpout ?

Comment: the value of x as a whole should be a string `x = "18.00 /34"
a = x.split(" /")`

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because during runtime, you usually don't have access to the actual source code. I guess the python interpreter would also directly calculate the result of the division when interpreting it.

Comment: Use: `re.split(r'\s*/\s*', x)`

Comment: You can use the [fraction module in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) to convert a number to a fraction

Comment: Is there a problem with my question ? I can't understand why someone put a negativ vote on it